# SwiftUI CoreData: Append CoreData-element to an array when view load (or is there a better way?)

Tags: swift, xcode, core-data, swiftui, double

in my current project I work for the first time with Core Data in SwiftUI. After many problems I am now I able to show the data in a list with the following code:

```
@FetchRequest(entity: SensorData.entity(), sortDescriptors: []) var sensorData: FetchedResults<SensorData>

List(sensorData, id: \.self){temp in
            Text("\(temp.temperatur)")
        }
```

(The Data is written to the CoreData-model somewhere else and that works fine)

In my model I have one entity (SensorData) with one attribute temperature with the type Double.

So, at that point every thing is fine and I get a list with every entry. But I want to show the data in a diagram and for that I need the entries in a Double array. How do I do this? I tried this:

```
var temperatures: [Double] = []

init(){
    for temp in sensorData{
        temperatures.append(temp.temperatur)
    }
}

LineView(data: temperatures, title: "Temperatur")
            .padding()
            .frame(height: 500, alignment: .center)
```

Here I get the error: Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)

Also I have set the type of the attribute to Transformabel and there to [Double]. Then I have written the data to the model like this:

```
if let temperatur = Double(temperatur){
   let sensorData = SensorData(context: self.viewContext)
   sensorData.temperatur?.append(temperatur)
                                                    
   try? self.viewContext.save()
}
```

But now I get the error:

Thread 1: Fatal error: Unresolved error Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134140 "Persistent store migration failed, missing mapping model." UserInfo={destinationModel=(<NSManagedObjectModel: 0x600001044af0>) isEditable 0, entities {
SensorData = "(<NSEntityDescription: 0x60000045c4d0>) name SensorData, managedObjectClassName SensorData, renamingIdentifier SensorData, isAbstract 0, superentity name (null), properties {\n    temperatur = "(<NSAttributeDescription: 0x600001d7af80>), name temperatur, isOptional

Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 1):

The error is arising because you changed the data model.  CoreData is trying to do a migration to the new model, but can't work out how.  If you are in development, just delete the app from the simulator/device and rerun.

But I'm not sure why you changed the model - do you want each `SensorData` object to have a `temperatur` attribute which is an *array* of Doubles?  Your previous model seemed fine, where you have an "array" of `SensorData` objects, each of which has (only one) Double as the `temperatur` attribute.  To pass the Doubles as an array to the LineView, use `map`:

```
LineView(data: sensorData.map() { $0.temperatur }, title: "Temperatur")
```